# Why does Windows Japanese locale make child process getenv return different value than was put with putenv?

Tags: c++, windows, localization, internationalization, environment-variables

Why doesn't the getenv result of a child process match exactly the value used in putenv of the parent process when the [Windows system locale](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7) is Japanese?

If my variable value is not using valid characters, **is there a range of valid hex values that are guaranteed valid for environment variables across all Windows system locals?**

When the locale is set to "English (United States)", the below sample program shows this behavior:

```
$ ./test.exe 1
parent: expected 13, got 13
 child: expected 13, got 13
```

When the system locale is set to "Japanese (Japan)", the same program (not recompiled) shows this different behavior:

```
$ ./test.exe 1
parent: expected 13, got 13
 child: expected 13, got 45
```

The first 5 characters match, but the 6th and 7th characters don't match.

---

Here is the sample program.  I compiled with the default Visual Studio 2012 "Win32 Console Application" new Project setting when unselecting "Precompiled header", unselecting "Security Development Lifecycle checks", and selecting "Empty Project" and adding the below as a "New Item" under "Source Files".  I am running Windows 7.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int index_6_value = 0x13;
    std::string label = argc == 2 ? "parent" : " child";
    const char name[] = { 0x73 /*s*/, 0 };
    char* before_insert = getenv(name);
    if ( argc == 1 && before_insert != 0) std::cout << label << ": expected " << std::hex << index_6_value << ", got " << int(before_insert[6]) << std::endl;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        //                                       0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
        char put_arg[] = { 0x73/*s*/, 0x3D/*=*/, 0x49, 0x73, 0xb0, 0xf6, 0xe3, 0x87, 0x13, 0 };
        putenv(put_arg);
        char* after_insert = getenv(name);
        if (after_insert) std::cout << label << ": expected " << std::hex << index_6_value << ", got " << int(after_insert[6]) << std::endl;

        std::string command = std::string("\"") + argv[0] + "\"";
        std::system(command.c_str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: GIGO. Bear in mind that there's probably a round trip from local narrow character set to UTF-16 and back involved, which may not be value preserving,  especially for random input. There are Unicode versions of `{get,set}env` in the MS CRT, as I recall, which may give more consistent results.

Comment: Is there a range of supported hex values that I can use for any Windows locale?  I can't find detailed Microsoft specific documentation about supported environment value characters, but the following suggests some restrictions http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html

Comment: There may be some subset of printable US-ASCII that works. But using the Unicode versions would be much more reliable.

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/cc305152) is the default Japanese encoding Windows uses: 0xf6 is the lead byte of a double-byte character (I did not check if 0xe3 is a valid trail byte). If you stick to 7-bit ASCII you should be safe. Still, I agree with Alan Stokes that using Unicode is usually safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putenv variable values should be restricted to printable ASCII values, otherwise Windows may not properly preserve the values depending on the local.  This isn't documented very well, but the idea is probably to avoid invalid multi-byte sequences in double byte locals, and you can see that the printable ASCII values (0x20-0x7E) are the same (valid) printable ASCII values in all code pages:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964654

Cross-platform and cross-local environment variable usage to store arbitrary bytes is difficult to do correctly and should probably be avoided.